# Instanciar funcion en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

¿Cual seria la mejor manera de instanciar una funcion de externa dentro de un controlador en laravel?

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php

namespace App\RandomCode;

class RandomCode
{
    function Generate()
    {
        $caracteres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"; 
        $numerodeletras=8;
        $cadena = "";
        for($i=0;$i<$numerodeletras;$i++)
        {
            $cadena .= substr($caracteres,rand(0,strlen($caracteres)),1);
        }
        return $cadena;
    }
}
```

en el directorio `App\Class`, el cual necesito llamarlo dentro de un controlador.

Comment: Deseas utilizar la funcion `Generate()` en otro controlador?.

Comment: Podrías hacerlo con un método estático, o mejor aún, podrías usar traits con laravel.

Comment: Si, necesito utilizar la funcion `Generate()` dentro de un controlador.

Comment: Hago esto para no utilizar la función directamente dentro del store.

Comment: Solucionado con Traits!!!

Comment: ¿Pero para qué Traits? No hace falta. La clase está dentro `app/`, por lo tanto solo hace uso del typehint en la función del controlador: `public function test(App\RandomCode $randomCode){`